# Using PhotoImage to display an image in Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, photoimage

I'm trying to create an application that has a main menu and a settings menu. I want to set background for each of these. But I'm starting with the settings menu. I'be been getting an error stating: 
`_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist`.
What am I doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

install_directory = '...'


# ***********************************MAIN MENU*****************************************************
def root():

    # ~~~Defines window~~~
    main_window = Tk()
    main_window.iconbitmap(install_directory + r'\resources\icons\logo.ico')  # Changes the icon for window
    main_window.title('Auto Transfer')  # Changes window name
    main_window.geometry("300x200")

    # ~~Adds a background~~~
    background = PhotoImage(file=install_directory + r'\resources\backgrounds\stardust.gif')
    label = Label(main_window, image=background)
    label.pack()

    # ~~~Menu Bar~~~
    menubar = Menu(main_window)  # Creates the menu bar

    # ~~~File menu~~~
    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Quit", command=lambda: main_window.destroy())  # Exits the program

    # ~~~Settings menu~~~
    settingsmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    settingsmenu.add_command(label="Change settings...", command=lambda: options(main_window))

    # ~~~Add menus to bar~~~
    menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=filemenu)
    menubar.add_cascade(label='Settings', menu=settingsmenu)

    # ~~Adds menu bar to the screen~~~
    main_window.config(menu=menubar)

    # ~~Adds 'RUN' button~~


    # ~~~Runs window~~~
    main_window.mainloop()


# *********************************OPTIONS MENU****************************************************
def options(main_window):

    options_window = Toplevel()
    options_window.iconbitmap(install_directory + r'\resources\icons\logo.ico')  # Changes the icon for window
    options_window.title('Settings')  # Changes window name
    options_window.geometry("720x480")

    # ~~Adds a background~~~
    background = PhotoImage(file=install_directory + r'\resources\backgrounds\stardust.gif')
    label = Label(options_window, image=background)
    label.pack()




# *******************************RUN APP**************************************************************
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root()
```

Comment: which line gives the error?

Comment: These lines are where the picture is supposed to be displayed:
`background = PhotoImage(file = install_directory + r'\resources\backgrounds\subtle.gif')
    label = Label(options_window, image=background)
    label.pack()`

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that you use two `Tk()` instances in your code. This is not very good. A tkinter application should only have one mainloop (i.e. one instance Tk()). To make other windows, use TopLevel widget.

Use this in your options function instead of making new Tk():

```
 options_window = Toplevel()
```

Hope this helps. Also make sure your image file paths are correct.

Comment: That got rid of the error, but the picture is still not showing up in the options window. I just used the same code:
`    background = PhotoImage(file='...')
    label = Label(options_window, image=background)
    label.pack()`
to add the same background to the main window, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide updated code.